# npm install vulnerabilities node_modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, postcss

I've tried update the packages on these vulnerabilities packages, there are: css-select, svgo, @svgr/plugin-svgo, @svgr/webpack, postcss, resolve-url-loader, but, it's depends on react-scripts 3.0.1, also I'm on 5.0.1 It's anything to do?

$ npm audit

## npm audit report

```
nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo/node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          node_modules/react-scripts

postcss  <8.4.31
Severity: moderate
PostCSS line return parsing error - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7fh5-64p2-3v2j
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader

**8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)**

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

My package.json

```
{
    "name": "mYproject",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "homepage": "https://myproject.cc",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "-": "^0.0.1",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.16",
        "@mui/material": "^5.14.17",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.14.17",
        "@mui/system": "5.14.11",
        "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.18.1",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
        "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
        "ajv": "^8.12.0",
        "ajv-keywords": "^5.1.0",
        "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
        "axios": "^1.6.1",
        "base-64": "^1.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
        "eslint": "^8.53.0",
        "filesize": "^10.1.0",
        "firebase": "^10.6.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.2",
        "helmet": "^7.1.0",
        "history": "^5.3.0",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
        "http-browserify": "^1.7.0",
        "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "npm": "^10.2.3",
        "nth-check": "^2.1.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.31",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.1",
        "react-calendar": "^4.6.1",
        "react-cookie-consent": "^9.0.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^4.21.0",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
        "react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
        "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
        "react-phone-number-input": "^3.3.7",
        "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.18.0",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
        "reactjs-social-login": "^2.6.3",
        "reactstrap": "^9.2.1",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
        "sendpulse-api": "^1.1.6",
        "svgo": "^3.0.2",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.9",
        "web-vitals": "^3.5.0",
        "webpack": "5.88.2",
        "workbox-background-sync": "^6.6.0",
        "workbox-build": "^7.0.0",
        "workbox-core": "^7.0.0",
        "workbox-expiration": "^7.0.0",
        "workbox-precaching": "^7.0.0",
        "workbox-range-requests": "^7.0.0",
        "workbox-routing": "^7.0.0",
        "workbox-strategies": "^7.0.0",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "7.0.0",
        "workbox-window": "^7.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browser": {
        "crypto": false,
        "stream": false,
        "fs": false,
        "path": false,
        "os": false,
        "http": false
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.23.3",
        "@jridgewell/sourcemap-codec": "^1.4.15",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.5.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
    },
    "webpack": [
        "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
    ]
}
```

I've tried update the packages `npm install postcss@latest` and `npm install nth-check@latest`

Comment: if you have the time, I highly recommend migrating from create-react-app to vite. This will remove the react-scripts dependency. Regarding postcss, maybe uninstalling it and re-installing will help

Answer (score 0):

```
nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
```

for this high vulnerabilities i saw this variant:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13364

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).